AWS Fargate Service - Incoming traffic health, but no outgoing traffic health
I have an ECS Fargate task that uses service connect to connect to a load balancer. Everything works, however there are no outgoing traffic health metrics, while there are incoming metrics. There is definitely outgoing traffic as I can communicate with the service through the load balancer.


Also the main container has a health status of Unknown, maybe this is related?

I've spent a lot of time trawling through the docs, but it's not clear to me how to resolve these final issues. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Incoming traffic refers to all traffic that originates outside of your network. These are requests that people are making to your application, and the responses that your application replies with. When something makes an HTTP request to your service, a connection is established, and the response is returned via that connection. This is the full lifecycle of an incoming request.
Also, notice that the "traffic health" view you show really isn't indicating if anything is "healthy" or "unhealthy". It is just showing some metrics for requests and connections.

There is definitely outgoing traffic as I can communicate with the service through the load balancer.

No, that is still considered part of the incoming traffic. Load balancers only deal with incoming traffic.
An outgoing request would be a request initiated by software running on your ECS service. For example if your application downloaded a file from another website, that would be an outgoing request from your application because your application initiated the request.

Also the main container has a health status of Unknown, maybe this is related?

No, those health checks are based on the optional Container Health Check feature where you give ECS some sort of command to run periodically inside your container, and it uses the return code from that command to determine the health of the container.

I suggest using the metrics reported by your load balancer and target group to AWS CloudWatch for determining the actual health of your application.

thanks. So the outgoing stats don't tell me what the status codes being returned as a response from the container are, but tell me about the responses that are requested by the container?

What outgoing stats? There are no outgoing stats are there? Wasn't that part of your original question? If you want to know the status codes returned as responses by your application, there are Load Balancer metrics for that (see the last link in my answer).

Yes, thanks. I was just confirming I'd understood correctly.
